# Android Studio development store arrays online

Tags: android, arrays, database, cloud, storage

I am having difficulty wading through the insane amount of information on this topic so bear with me if this has been asked before.

I am a fairly good programmer when it comes to javascript and have made a simple app designed for sports league management. I need a way to store a few arrays online that get downloaded when the app opens, then saved back online if the user adds/edits/deletes elements from those arrays.

What is the simplest/cheapest way to do this? I am overwhelmed by the seemingly endless ways to store data online and desperately need guidance! Please provide a tutorial or step by step guide if you can, I am woefully inexperienced when it comes to online storage.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Create json object, and use RESTful APIs to store and/or retrieve that object when needed. You can even use a JSONArray if you want.

Comment: I guess the cheapest solution would be storing the data locally on the device and making use of the Android Backup Service (see http://developer.android.com/google/backup/index.html) that promises to provide you with some cloud storage for user preferences etc. However, haven't tried that one and as far as I can tell, the backend is device-specific. Alternatively you could make use of the user's Dropbox account (or other cloud storage) and save data there; that's also at no extra running cost for you.

Comment: Nobu, is there a way to store a SQLite database online (say in a dropbox or something) where the app could download it on start and save it periodically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON for this. If you are using Arrays, try using JSONArray.

```
ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Hello");
list.add("World");
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(list);
```

Use RESTful API to store, retrieve and edit the information as you see fit. For a tutorial on how to do REST, here is a decent one: http://api.shephertz.com/tutorial/Saving-App-Data/